# Server response "unsupported media type" when I send JSON format data to Asp.net Core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core

Visual Studio 2019
Asp.Net Core 3.0

A. Unsupported media type code

```
    $.ajax({
        url: this.url,
        data: jsonDataParameter,
        cache: false,
        type: "Post",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {}
        });
```

B. Successful request code

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.url,
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonDataParameter),
    cache: false,
    type: "Post",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {}
    });
```

Here is my questions:
Is this features or Bugs?
If it is features, why?

Thank you ahead.

Comment: What's in `jsonDataParameter`?

Comment: Just JSON like {a:1,b:2} which is mapping the model class

Comment: What does your post action look like?Do you use [FromBody]?

Comment: This `{a:1,b:2}` is not a valid JSON. You need to convert it to JSON before sending the request as you are doing it in your second approach.

Answer (score 2):

`contentType` is the type of data you're sending, and `application/json; charset=utf-8` is a common one to send json data.

In your case, data `{a:1,b:2}` is only a Javascript object so you need to use the `JSON.stringify()` method to convert a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string.

Since your content type is `application/json;`, you need to use [FromBody] and receive the data as an object based on your situation.